# "Next" button doesn't refresh page with next 25 results

Tags: php, sql

I have the code below and am trying to get the next 25 results from my sql table to appear on page.  However, whenever I click the next button, no information is displayed.  I have my offset = ($page - 1) * $items_per_page......I'm struggling to figure this out as it seems so simple compared the other code I've written, but is proving to be very elusive to me....any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  My primary issue is that the next link does not provide the next 25 results and I'm unable to determine why and how to correct.

```
                            echo "<h3 style='text-align:center;'>Welcome to the Exchange Portal,&nbsp;" . $row['name'] . "!&nbsp;</h3>";


                            $items_per_page = 25;


                            $sql_count = "SELECT pin, title, title2, email, phone FROM crown_acura";
                            $result_cnt = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_count);

                            if(false === $result_cnt) {
                                throw new Exception('Query failed with: ' . mysqli_error());
                                } else {
                                   $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result_cnt);
                                   // free the result set as you don't need it anymore
                                   //mysqli_free_result($result_cnt);
                                }

                                echo $row_count;
                                echo "&nbsp;";

                                if (!isset($_GET['Page'])) {
                                    $Page = 1;
                                } else {
                                    $Page = $_GET['Page'];
                                }
                                echo $page;
                                echo "&nbsp;";

                                $page_count = 0;
                                if (0 === $row_count) {  
                                    // maybe show some error since there is nothing in your table
                                } else {
                                  // determine page_count
                                   $page_count = (int)ceil($row_count / $items_per_page);
                                   // double check that request page is in range
                                   if($page > $page_count) {
                                        // error to user, maybe set page to 1
                                        $page = 1;
                                   }
                                }
                                echo "&nbsp;";
                                echo $page_count;
                                echo "&nbsp;";
                                echo $items_per_page;

                                $offset = ($page-1)*$items_per_page;


                                //echo $paging_info;
                                //echo "&nbsp;";
                                echo "<br />";

                            //Query for displaying results
                            $list_sql = "SELECT pin, title, title2, email, phone FROM crown_acura LIMIT $offset, $items_per_page";
                            $result_query = $conn->query($list_sql);

                                //Table for displaying query results
                                echo "<table class='verify'>";
                                echo "<tr >";
                                echo "<td><h3>Name</h3></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><h3>E-mail</h3></td><td><h3>Phone</h3></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                                for($i = 1; $i<= $page_count; $i++) {
                                    if ($result_query->num_rows > 0) {
                                        // output data of each row
                                        while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_query)) {
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<td class='dltd2 dlcl'>" . $row3["title"] . "</td><td>" . $row3["title2"] . "</td><td><a href='mailto:" . $row3['email'] . "'>" . $row3["email"] . "</a>&nbsp;</td><td>" . $row3["phone"] . "&nbsp;</td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";   
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        echo "0 results";   
                                    }
                                }
                                echo "<tr></tr>";


                                $next_page = $page + 1;
                                $last_page = $page - 1;

                                if($paging_info['curr_page'] <= 1) {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td></td><td colspan='2'><a class='loadlink' href='" . $_PHP_SELF . "'>Next 25</a></td><td></td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                } elseif ($paging_info['curr_page'] < $page_count) {
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td></td><td><a href='" . $_PHP_SELF . "?page=" . $last_page . "'>Prev 25</a></td><td><a href='" . $_PHP_SELF . "?page=" . $next_page . "'>Next 25</a></td><td></td>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                        } elseif ($paging_info['curr_page'] === $page_count) {
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<td></td><td colspan='2'><a href='" . $_PHP_SELF . "?page=" . $last_page . "'>Prev 25</a></td><td></td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                            }

                                echo "</table>";
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: what is purpose of your for loop `for($i = 1; $i<= $page_count; $i++)`? Why are you trying to do `while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_query))` for every page?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure....not that you mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run the rendered SQL.

Output to browser:

```
"SELECT pin, title, title2, email, phone FROM crown_acura LIMIT $offset, $items_per_page"
```

Comment: can you expand on this?  my query is actually running as it displayed the requested information and limiting it to first 25 (or next 25 is I manually change the value of the $offset variable).

Comment: echo( $list_sql ) - to see what is being sent to MYSQL.

Comment: SELECT pin, title, title2, email, phone FROM crown_acura LIMIT 0, 25 -this is what is displayed on page when I echo $list_sql

Comment: I feel like when you click "next 25" this should somehow change $offset = 25 and the query rerun on same page....but I have no idea how to make that happen.....and should change $page = 2......

Answer (score -1):

try this... and change $page for different values (2,3,...,etc)

```
<?php

$items_per_page = 25;

$sql_count = "SELECT pin, title, title2, email, phone FROM crown_acura";
$result_cnt = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_count);

if (false === $result_cnt) {
    throw new Exception('Query failed with: ' . mysqli_error());
} else {
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result_cnt);
    // free the result set as you don't need it anymore
    //mysqli_free_result($result_cnt);
}

echo $row_count;
echo "&nbsp;";

if (!isset($_GET['Page'])) {
    $Page = 1;
} else {
    $Page = $_GET['Page'];
}
echo $page;
echo "&nbsp;";

$page_count = 0;
if (0 === $row_count) {
    // maybe show some error since there is nothing in your table
} else {
    // determine page_count
    $page_count = (int)ceil($row_count / $items_per_page);
    // double check that request page is in range
    if ($page > $page_count) {
        // error to user, maybe set page to 1
        $page = 1;
    }
}
echo "&nbsp;";
echo $page_count;
echo "&nbsp;";
echo $items_per_page;

$offset = ($page - 1) * $items_per_page;


//echo $paging_info;
//echo "&nbsp;";
echo "<br />";

//Query for displaying results
$list_sql = "SELECT pin, title, title2, email, phone FROM crown_acura LIMIT $offset, $items_per_page";
$result_query = $conn->query($list_sql);


echo ("RESULTS: ".$result_query->num_rows());
```

?>

Comment: For educational purposes it is always a good idea to write a description of why you think your code works, what you have changed compared to original code or where the OP's mistake was.